# I am trying to post a question and it says my question body does not meet the standards

Tags: bug, status-norepro

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G530T

  - OS Version: 5.1.1 (G530TUVS2AQE3)

Comment: You are trying to post a question where? What was your question?

Comment: Please add more detail to this. What is the exact wording of your question and what exactly happens?

Comment: Is [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/90250/49) by any chance the question you tried to ask? If yes, is the problem from this bug report still happening or has this basically been resolved?

Comment: @Napoleon As this quality filter is working as intended, Shouldn't you edit question tags to by design?

Comment: @NogShine It seems we don't actually know *why* his question was declined, though. And he ultimately got it posted afterall.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't a bug. The system is working as intended. It happens to users here and there.

It is one of the quality checks system performs on questions in order to avoid poor questions. It is not exactly known what in your question triggered the quality check. But here are some of the possible reasons why you get such message :

> #### What can I do to get the system to accept my question?
>
> Make sure your question has
>
> - a clear title
> - a reasonable *explanation* of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
> - correct use of English and actual sentences
> - proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation

Read [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075/357396) for more details. So, consider using proper tags, writing a good title, *proper spelling* (not the internet slang kind), punctuation and grammar. Also read some [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/asking) pages to avoid the message in future.

Answer (score -4):

I think its working well now cuz I just tried to post a question and it worked